# Why is there an unmatched parenthesis in this title?

Tags: syntax

This Asahi Shinbun article has an unmatched right parenthesis in its title:
[岩手）震災の教訓を考える　「人間復興大学」１０日開学](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASG4S51M0G4SUJUB00B.html)

Surely, Japanese syntactic rules disallow unmatched parenthesis, right?
Asahi Shinbun just made a mistake (in a title no less), correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a mistake, it's just a stylistic choice.  They do it all the time:

> [長野）松本山雅がホーム初勝利　岐阜に１―０](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASG4V452VG4VUOOB005.html)
>   [愛媛）愛媛ＦＣ、松本山雅に競り負け　４戦白星なし](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASG533F1VG53PFIB001.html)
>   [岐阜）船来山古墳群、国史跡へ調査本腰　近畿外で最大級](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASG4Z5K8DG4ZOHGB00Q.html)
>   [長野）ＳＫＦ、バレエ二山さんと共演へ　９月](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASG4X51RXG4XUOOB010.html)
>   [青森）原発の電源喪失防げ　東北電が送電線工事公開](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASG4R447BG4RUBNB002.html)
>   [茨城）原電がウェブで資料公開　東海第二の安全審査巡り](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASG4Q3GY5G4QUJHB001.html)
>   [長野）上高地で開山祭　観光シーズン本番に](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASG4W4QTVG4WUOOB00C.html)

I only spent about 30 seconds looking through headlines to find these examples—I'm not picking out anything rare.  You've probably noticed that each one "tags" the article with the name of a prefecture:

> 長野県（ながのけん）
>   愛媛県（えひめけん）
>   岐阜県（ぎふけん）
>   青森県（あおもりけん）
>   茨城県（いばらきけん）
>   岩手県（いわてけん）

Your example "tags" the article as being relevant to 岩手県.